# Cassava Skip or Ignore Columns

Tags: csv, haskell

So I have a decent grasp on Cassava for simple use cases but I have this one .csv that has 25 columns, and I only care about the 2nd and 5th columns. Is there any way to do a partial parse of each line or do I need to make 20 `_ :: Text` parameter declarations in the labmda declaration like below?

```
Right v -> V.forM_ v $ \ (_ :: Text, thingA :: Text, _ :: Text,  _ :: Text,  _ :: Text, thingB :: Text,,  _ :: Text,  _ :: Text,  _ :: Text ..... etc
```

Edit: Also just discovered there's no instance for a 25 column CSV anyhow so even my ridiculous 336 character signature can't work.

Edit': Seems that one solution might be named records (suggested [here](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Loading-a-csv-file-with-200-columns-into-Haskell-Record-tp5865153p5865195.html) as a fix for dealing with super wide documents] )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own `FromRecord` instance for this.  You just need to write a `parseRecord` method that takes a `Record` (which is type `Vector Field`), extracts the desired columns at indexes 1 and 4, and loads them into your data type.

Something like the following will work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Text (Text)

data SomeFields = SomeFields Text Text deriving (Show)
instance FromRecord SomeFields where
  parseRecord r = SomeFields <$> parseField (r V.! 1) <*> parseField (r V.! 4)

main = do
  print $ (decode NoHeader "1,2,3,4,5,6,7\na,b,c,d,e,f,g\n"
           :: Either String (V.Vector SomeFields))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving it this way.

```
data ThingAtoThinBMapping = ThingAtoThinBMapping {
      thingA :: Text
    , thingB :: Text
} deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance FromNamedRecord ThingAtoThinBMapping where
    parseNamedRecord r = ThingAtoThinBMapping 
        <$> r .: "thing_a"
        <*> r .: "thing_b"

printABMap = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "reallywide.csv"
    case decodeByNameWith decodeOpts csvData of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right (h, v) -> do
            putStrLn $ show h
            V.forM_ v $ \ m ->
                putStrLn $ show (thingA m, thingB m)
```